# ADO.NET Entity Framework - Oracle with Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my solution which uses an Oracle database (ODP.NET), but I get the following error:

> "Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework;
>   however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this
>   version could not be found for your data connection.  If you have
>   already installed a compatible provider, ensure you have rebuilt your
>   project before performing this action.  Otherwise, exit this wizard,
>   install a compatible provider, and rebuild your project before
>   performing this action."

The dialog also says it is trying to use Entity Framework 6.x.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and it's an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application.  I have installed 64-bit ODAC 12c Release 3 (12.1.0.2.1) for Windows x64.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install 32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) 
with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio. 
You can download it from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html) web site.

Comment: I got the same message after installing ODAC 12.2c Release 1 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.2.0.1.0).  I was trying to create an ADO.NET Entoty Data model using the wizard - EF Designer from database, and Code First from database.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and wrote a about it [here](http://www.fayed.org/2017/11/oracle-managed-driver-and-entity.html) , this is because my App.Config file contains binding information related to a different Oracle Managed Driver DLLs version and there is a simple solution to this error :)

I just to remove this version specific data from App.config file and rebuild the application.

so instead of :

```
  <system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
  <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
```

it will be :

```
  <system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
  <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
```